# How add age_range to Graph Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I use Facebook Api. I connect to api with Facebook c# SDK. 
How add **age_range** to this query

```
search?limit=5000&offset=0&type=user&q=Peter

var apptoken = result.access_token;
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.q = "uk";
parameters.limit="5000";
parameters.offset = "0";
parameters.type = "adgeolocation";
parameters.type = "user";
parameters.q = "Peter";

var searchedPlaces = fbClient.Get("/search", parameters);
var vihod = (from i in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)searchedPlaces.data
             select new
             {
                 i.name,
                 i.id
             }).ToList();
```

Comment: why are you sending multiple values for 'type'? and q? I'm not sure there is an `age_range` parameter on the user (or adgeolocation) search endpoint - where did you see one documented?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/K823OLzZC68g2O.png?d=

Comment: That screenshot isn't from the docs and i'm unsure what it's intended to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to filter on `age_range`, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#readmodifiers. Not sure why you'd need this at all...

And, as @Igy pointed out, you're overwriting your `parameter.type` variable two times, but this is not really related to your question.